# How to make required attribute configurable in .gsp file

Tags: html, grails

In Grails application I have domain, which have filed 'typeOfForm'.
Depend on value of 'typeOfForm' some fields become mandatory and prohibited (typeOfForm is set during creation and can not be changed).

Now in gsp file (for example in g:textField) I need to set attributes disabled and required

I have implemented

```
 <%
 def fieldRequired = ...
 def fieldProhibeted = ...
 %>
```

and

```
<g:textField ...  disabled="${fieldProhibeted}" required="${fieldRequired}"/>
```

My problem is with required attribute.
If required attribute is there field become mandatory regardless of value.

My current workaround/solution is to 'override' g:textField and create myTaglib and remove required attribute if value is false.

Can you suggest any nice solution please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe a simple if/elseif will solve your problem.

```
<g:if test="${fieldRequired}">
  <g:textField required="required" .... />
</g:if>
</g:elseif test="${fieldProhibeted}">
  <g:textField disabled="disabled" ... />
</g:elseif>
```